# How can I compute SVD and and verify that the ratio of the first-to-last singular value is sane with OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, svd

I want to verify that homography matrix will give good results and this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10981249/1910724)
 has an answer for it - but, I don't know how to implement the answer. 
So can anyone recommend how I may use OpenCV to compute SVD and and verify that the ratio of the first-to-last singular value is sane?

Comment: Hello Tony, I have the same question you are doing. And I can see how to compute SVD, but I still don't understand the part of "verify that the ratio of the first-to-last singular value is sane".
Could you solve this?.
Thank you

Comment: There were no exact solution for this. I made a lot of tests for my specific problem and decided a threshold value myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to compute the SVD in OpenCV:

```
cv::SVD homographySVD(homography, cv::SVD::FULL_UV); // constructor
// or: 
homographySVD(newHomography, cv::SVD::FULL_UV); // operator ()
homographySVD.w.at<double>(0, 0); // access the first singular value

// alternatives:
cv::SVD::compute(homography, w); // compute just the singular values
cv::eigen(homography, w);
```

Have a look at the documentation for [cv::SVD](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=svd#SVD) and [cv::eigen](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=svd#bool%20eigen%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20eigenvalues,%20int%20lowindex,%20int%20highindex%29) for more details.

Comment: Could someone contribute the same in Python?

Answer (score 3):

You can compute SVD in python using `numpy`.
For example:

```
    import numpy as np
    U, s, V = np.linalg.svd(a, full_matrices=True)
```

which factors the matrix `a` of dimension `M x N` as `u * np.diag(s) * v`, where `u` and `v` are unitary and `s` is a 1-d array of `a`'s singular values.

More can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html).